# Apache keeps giving error on rewrite directives

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having troubles with Apachen allowing me to use rewrite rules in my .htaccess file in a subfolder. Every time I try to access the page, I get the following error in my Apache log.

```
/var/www/main/clients/.htaccess: RewriteEngine not allowed here, referer: http://www.website.com/
```

The .htaccess file is currently,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule ^index.html subfolder/index.html
</IfModule>
```

As suggested in all of the help I can find, I've already verified that `mod_rewrite` is enabled and `AllowOverride` is set in the main config file (below). There are also no other .htaccess files anywhere else in the tree.

```
<VirtualHost *>

  DocumentRoot /var/www/main/document/root/folder

  Alias /clients "/var/www/main/clients"

  <Directory /var/www/main/clients/>
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anybody see anything I've missed or suggest how I can diagnose what is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that your `DocumentRoot` is not same as the path in `Directory` directive.

Change `DocumentRoot` line to:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/main/clients/
```

And restart your Apache.

Comment: No that didn't fix it. And I do need to have the main document root point to another folder with just the clients in a different location.

Comment: Well you cannot have .htaccess outside your DocumentRoot. You can keep .htaccess in `/var/www/main/clients` but keep DocumentRoot as `/var/www`

Comment: Actually you can because its working fine now exactly as I put it in the question. 

I found out the problem. Sometime in the past someone was monkeying around with configs and had multiple configs with similar parameters. Once I sorted out which one was being used and edited that, it worked perfectly!